# BreezeJS's 1.4.1 isolateES5Props causing Out of Stack Space error in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, breeze

Using 1.4.1 of BreezeJS we found that some new code added to Isolate ES5 Properties is causing IE 8 to have the following error:

Error getting metadata: Metadata import failed for breeze/breeze/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:Object doesn't support property or method 'getPrototypeOf'

We tried using both Uber Proto's getPrototypeOf (https://github.com/daffl/uberproto) and es5-sham (https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) but both result with the same issue.

We also tried removing the regular json.parse and using json2's version with the same results.

Metadata import failed for /breeze/breeze/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:Out of stack space

Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9+ work without issue, but IE 8 support is required. We can comment out the line to get it to work:

```
 // isolateES5Props(proto);
```

But I'm guessing that will cause issues somewhere down the line.

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue.  It would be nice to know of a workaround!

Comment: @SeanPrice I posted the workaround for now, just comment out that line and it will work in IE 8 again, not sure of any side effects though since its a new addition to breeze

Comment: I actually had a slightly different error than yours (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452732/javascript-message-out-of-stack-space-in-ie8).  And actually, your workaround worked!  I am also a little hesitant about what problems may arise from it, but for the time being it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: John, because your workaround is a good answer for the time being, do you mind adding it as an answer to your own question?  I'll upvote it so that any others that stumble upon this will notice.

Comment: Because IE8 doesn't suport ES5 properties there isn't much to worry about with a method called `isolateES5Props`. Thanks for the clue about `getPrototypeOf` triggering the infinite loop. We ought to be able to detect and work around that one.

Comment: As a note on this one, I just ran into the same problem and commented out that line and we now have no errors in IE8.  Was hard to find this question though, spent basically all day on the issue.

Comment: @Ward Up until now I've found Breeze does not require es5-sham, only es5-shim. If you are going to start using getPrototypeOf and getOwnPropertyDescriptor, please consider adding built-in shams for these like you have already done for Object.create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in Breeze v 1.4.2, available now.

Comment: We ended up just dropping IE 8 support since it was causing too many other issues and so slow in general. I'll take your word that it was fixed though! :)

Comment: Just to reflect on that question, I am using Breeze v 1.4.4 and am still encountering that error. The workaround worked perfectly for me on ie8.