# Javascript Message Out of Stack Space in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, breeze

I'm using Breeze 1.4.1, Internet Explorer 8, and ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API.  I received the following message when querying:

> Query failed: Metadata import failed for localhost:port/breeze/Data/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:Out of stack space

It works on firefox/chrome.  Any suggestions on a workaround?  Unfortunately I am stuck with IE8 for production code.

Comment: See answer .... SO won't let me delete my own comment

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed the [Breeze supported browsers](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/prerequisites) page? It describes certain shims that are necessary if you use IE8.

In general, after shimming, Breeze has no trouble importing metadata in IE8. There isn't enough information in your question for us to even hazard a guess as to what is going wrong.

Perhaps you can debug into it and find where the import is breaking down.

Comment: Hey Ward, I really appreciate you responding.  I dived into the code and tried debugging it.  When doing so (for about 10 minutes), the error changed from "out of stack space" to something where the the stringparse function does not exist.  I imagine this whole thing occurs due to the stack space limit in IE8 for recursion logic.  Overall, my solution was to use the workaround given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412752/breezejss-1-4-1-isolatees5props-causing-out-of-stack-space-error-in-ie-8.  This was to comment out //isolateES5Props(proto); inside of the breeze.debug.js file.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did follow the instructions of what you provided as well for the supported browsers.  I have included the shim/sham files appropriately and have verified another project was working just fine.  Similar to John in the other question, it makes me hesitant to just randomly comment out something in a library...

Comment: Thanks, Sean. This is news to me ... unwelcome news but glad to have it. We'll take a look at it as soon as we can.

Comment: @Ward I have more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412752/breezejss-1-4-1-isolatees5props-causing-out-of-stack-space-error-in-ie-8 it is the getPrototypeOf method that doesn't work and causes a recursive loop until it runs out of memory

Comment: Ward, I'm a big fan of breeze and would love to help in anyway I can.  The project I experienced this issue on was very small one-pager and cornered it down to occurring even with a one-table local database.  The metadata is as small as it could get.  I can zip it up and send it to you if you would like for recreation.  The version of IE is 8.0.7601.17514.  Let me know if it helps for me to log it over on github, and I can assist further on it.

Comment: You can also use IE 9 / 10 and use the developer tools to change the Document Mode to IE 8 to cause it to fail if you don't have an XP box.