# Breezejs - Metadata import error on IE8

Tags: breeze

I have been running a project using Breezejs for a few months now, and everything was working quite fine up to when I updated to latest version ("1.4.5") and metadata import stopped working on IE8.

I was previously working with version "1.3.6" and it was running ok in IE8 (I have added es5-shims and json2 libraries as suggested, for "legacy" browser support).

Since I upgraded to latest version, however, when initializing a new entity manager and issuing the first query it returns the following error:

```
    Unable to either parse or import metadata: [Object expected]
```

in the *ctor.prototype.fetchMetadata* method.

Tracing down the issue, I've come to understand that it fails running *getES5PropDescriptor* method **on client-side added properties for entities extended with custom constructors** (as specified on Breeze documentation [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities)):

```
function getES5PropDescriptor(proto, propName) {

    if (proto.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        //next line throws the error!!!
        return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, propName);
    } else {
        var nextProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
        return nextProto ? getES5PropDescriptor(nextProto, propName) : null;
    }
}
```

Is this a known issue in Breezejs? Any hint about how to make it work again on IE8 with latest Breezejs version?

I've also tried following suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412752/breezejss-1-4-1-isolatees5props-causing-out-of-stack-space-error-in-ie-8) (basically commenting out invocation of *isolateES5Props* method), but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance for your precious support!

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

This has been fixed as of Breeze 1.4.7, available now.

### Previous Post:

This is a bug.  It will be fixed in the next version.  A fix will also be checked into GitHub later today (just pull the breeze.xxx.js files). For now you can modify breeze.debug.js by adding the following function.

```
function canIsolateES5Props() {
    try {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf && Object.defineProperty({}, 'x', {});
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and calling it at the top of the getES5PropDescriptor function.

```
function getES5PropDescriptor(proto, propName) {
    if (!canIsolateES5Props()) return null;
    ...
    // code from above
}
```